# Incorrect android:id and android:contentDescription show up in uiautomatorviewer

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

I am setting the tags of my menu from an xml file which is as follows:

```
<menu .....>
      <item android:id="@+id/action_logout" android:title="@string/action_logout"
      android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never"
      android:contentDescription="Logout" />
</menu>
```

But when I view my menu from the `uiautomatorviewer` or `appium` inspector I am not seeing the correct `Id` or `contentDescription` showing up.

Oddly enough the title values do flow in every time and are correctly displayed but not the `Id` and `ContentDesc`.

The `UIAutomatorViewer` output shows:

> resource-id = android:id/title (which has wrong package name as well as wrong id)
>
> content-Desc: (It shows up as blank)

Has anybody else encountered this kind of issue and whats the solution for this?

Comment: Seeing the same issue. Did you find a solution @Brahma ?